# Spring MVC 3.1.1 and JBoss 7.1 can't get the static content to work

Tags: spring-mvc, jboss, static-content

I am using Eclipse with JBoss support installed, and have setup JBoss 7.1 as my server of choice.

In my Spring MVC Application i have the following structure

```
    main/webapp/resources/static/{css,img,js}
    main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/messages_XX.properties
    main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/<name>.jsp
```

my dispatcher-context.xml contains the following

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc.test" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources" />
```

And it doesn't work

i have tried reaching the content using different paths:

```
    <ip>:8080/test/resources/static/img/logo.png
    <ip>:8080/resources/static/img/logo.png
    <ip>:8080/test/static/img/logo.png
```

but it always returns 404, e.g.

```
    HTTP Status 404 - /resources/static/img/logo.png
    type Status report
    message /resources/static/img/logo.png
    description The requested resource (/resources/static/img/logo.png) is not available.
    JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final
```

i already looked around and have tried different options mentioned by different people, but none of it works.

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are your files located in `/WebContent` or in `/webapp`? It could be that Spring is looking for them in `/WebContent/resources/`

Comment: Hi ipavlic, webapp is the root of the application, and is maven standard naming convention, spring can only access its sub-folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, surprisngly it works after recreating the context xmls from scratch again (and probobly fixing typos)

Changes:

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources" />
    to
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

*.jsp
Using jstl "c" instead of spring

```
    <c:url value="/resources/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    instead of
    <spring:url value="/resources/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

However i think it was the first change that made it work.